# Method Illuminate\Translation\Translator::getFromJson does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

After upgrading from laravel 5.8 to laravel 6.0, I found this error.

> `Method Illuminate\Translation\Translator::getFromJson does not exist`

Anyone know any work around for this?

It seems that problem is from using @lang for printing translation messages in my blade file

Comment: Have you checked document for the same?  https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#get-from-json

Comment: This is well explained guide for upgradation...  https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Hy Prasanth

The Lang::get and Lang::getFromJson methods have been consolidated in laravel . Calls to the Lang::getFromJson method should be updated to call Lang::get.

You should run the `php artisan view:clear` Artisan command to avoid Blade errors related to the removal of Lang::transChoice, Lang::trans, and Lang::getFromJson.

Thank you.

Comment: `Lang::getFromJson` accepts replacements as the second argument, whereas `Lang::get` does not, so they're not 100% compatible with each other. I'd suggest instead using `Lang::trans()` or simply `trans()`.

Answer (score 37):

Try `php artisan view:clear`

The issue is that your view files have been compiled in 5.8, so @lang has compiled to `Lang::getFromJson` which has now been removed.

Answer (score 7):

If `php artisan view:clear` doesn't work on debian server, maybe permission is denied.

Try `sudo rm storage/framework/views/*`

Answer (score 1):

Please use Lang::get('your name') in laravel 6