# custom email verification getFromJson does not exist

Tags: laravel-6

im noob on laravel i'm trying to set up a custom email verification on laravel 6
i get this error 
Method Illuminate\Translation\Translator::getFromJson does not exist.
i try
php artisan view:clear but didn't work for me 
any help please

[Method Illuminate\Translation\Translator::getFromJson does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58162258/method-illuminate-translation-translatorgetfromjson-does-not-exist)

Comment: i found the solution it must just replace Lang::getFromJson with Lang::get

Answer (score 1):

There are chances your application is still using outdated cache views. Try this

```
php artisan view:clear

php artisan view:cache
```